# How to parse and present JQuery-response

Tags: jquery

I receive a JSON-response after a Ajax-call to a WebMethod, and want to parse it and present the data in div-tags of the following format (the div-tags should be created dynamically).
I marked the attributes bold below that should be replaced by the equivalent properties of the JSON-response. Each news-item (encapsulated by { } in the JSON-response)- corresponds to one list-element.
Here follows how the data should be presented:

```
<div class="articleList-list"> 
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div class="articleList-image">
                            <img src="**ImageSource**" width="150px" height="100px" alt="the article's image" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="articleList-article">
                            <h3><a href="**UrlForNewsitem**">**OverskriftArticleData**</a></h3>
                            <p>**Ingress**</p>
                        </div>                
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="articleList-image">
                            <img src="#" width="150px" height="100px" alt="the article's image" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="articleList-article">
                            <h3><a href="#">Artikkel nummer 2s tittel</a></h3>
                            <p>Et kort sammendrag av hva artikkelen handler om, eller starten på selve artikkelen. 
                            Dette skal ligge til ventstre i hovedinnholdet, til høyre for artikkelens bilde og oversikten over alle artikkel-kategorier.</p>
                        </div>                
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Here is the JSON-response:

```
[{"ImageSource":"/ImageVaultFiles/id_1/cf_2/Person.JPG","OverskriftArticleData":"ArtikelOverskrift","UrlForNewsitem":"/Templates/Skien.inter/Pages/Aktuellt.aspx?id=2816&epslanguage=en","ByLineOfArticle":"ForfattareByline","Ingress":"Detta ær ingressen till artikeln"},{"ImageSource":"/ImageVaultFiles/id_10/cf_2/city.JPG","OverskriftArticleData":"Rubrik","UrlForNewsitem":"/Templates/Skien.inter/Pages/Aktuellt.aspx?id=2814&epslanguage=en","ByLineOfArticle":"Anders B","Ingress":"Testar ingress"}]
```

How do I in a neat and efficient way parse and present the JQuery-response?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730241/json-to-nested-unordered-list/12730310#12730310 . It hoes how to use the template Api plug-in.

Comment: @willsteel: One might need to start looking at jsRender instead of jQuery templates as jQuery templates has been discontinued and jsRender has taken it's place. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl#readme as per link `A templating plugin for jQuery. BETA. NO LONGER IN ACTIVE DEVELOPMENT OR MAINTENANCE. Issues remain open but are not being worked.`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your response is valid JSON, you don't need to parse it. You can use it directly because it's a valid javascript object. Your response appears to be an array with a single object, so you could use it like this:

```
data = [{"ImageSource":"/ImageVaultFiles/id_1/cf_2/Person.JPG","OverskriftArticleData":"ArtikelOverskrift","UrlForNewsitem":"/Templates/Skien.inter/Pages/Aktuellt.aspx?id=2816&epslanguage=en","ByLineOfArticle":"ForfattareByline","Ingress":"Detta ær ingressen till artikeln"},{"ImageSource":"/ImageVaultFiles/id_10/cf_2/city.JPG","OverskriftArticleData":"Rubrik","UrlForNewsitem":"/Templates/Skien.inter/Pages/Aktuellt.aspx?id=2814&epslanguage=en","ByLineOfArticle":"Anders B","Ingress":"Testar ingress"}];
var imgSource = data[0].ImageSource;
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks!
It should be valid JSON.
I used this at the server-side: http://json.codeplex.com/

I had to use this first in order for your suggestion to work:
data = JSON.parse(stringToParse);

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery parseJSON function. You can read more about it here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response_json);
//Now use the various properties of object which contain the values of json response.

$("articleList-article > img")[0].attribute("src", obj.ImageSource);

//And so on
```

Also you can simply use:

```
data = [{"ImageSource":"/ImageVaultFiles/id_1/cf_2/Person.JPG","OverskriftArticleData":"ArtikelOverskrift","UrlForNewsitem":"/Templates/Skien.inter/Pages/Aktuellt.aspx?id=2816&epslanguage=en","ByLineOfArticle":"ForfattareByline","Ingress":"Detta ær ingressen till artikeln"},{"ImageSource":"/ImageVaultFiles/id_10/cf_2/city.JPG","OverskriftArticleData":"Rubrik","UrlForNewsitem":"/Templates/Skien.inter/Pages/Aktuellt.aspx?id=2814&epslanguage=en","ByLineOfArticle":"Anders B","Ingress":"Testar ingress"}];
$("articleList-article > img")[0].attribute("src", data[0].ImageSource);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use templates, google .tmpl() or JsRender

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you're using jQuery to actually make the Ajax call, you can pass an additional `post` parameter to have it automatically decode it for you and pass it to your callback function:

```
$.post('/someUrl/', {some: 'object params'}, function myCallback(data) {
  /* here the data variable is an object */
  alert(data.something);
}, 'json');
```

This is, in effect, a POST version of `$.getJSON`.

Answer (score 0):

After receiving the JSON-response this is called:

```
function ParseAndPresentJquery(stringToParse, hrefNameOfTab) 
    {
        data = JSON.parse(stringToParse);

        var src = "<div class='articleList-list'><ul>";

        for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
            src += "<li><div class='articleList-article'><h3><a href='" + data[j].UrlForNewsitem + "'>";
            src += data[j].OverskriftArticleData + "</a></h3></div>";
            src += "<p>";
            src+= data[j].Ingress;
            src += "</p>";
            src += "</div></li>";
        }
        src += "</ul></div>";
        $(hrefNameOfTab).html("");
        $(hrefNameOfTab).append(src);
    }
```